# Did Pharisee Semichah tradition (rabbinic ordination) include tests?

Tags: rabbis, beit-din-court, semicha

IIRC, God commanded Moses to ordain Joshuah, so the latter hadn't had to pass any exams. The next 20 generations were all [considered] prophets, so I guess they had divine revelations also.

[image]

The Talmud mentioned Semichah in many places, but I don't recall any preceding test or close examination.

What about the following generations from Ezrah to the Talmudic Rabbis, those who weren't blessed with divine insight, how did they decide if a pupil was worthy of the Semichah?

Comment: Presumably just by knowing them well. Tests became necessary when people wanted semicha from Rabbis they did not personally know.